# Javafx Label creation results in NullPointerException

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, imageview, label

I'm trying to build my first **Javafx** project on **Netbeans**, and i'ven been stuck at adding an **imageview** for a **Label**, it always returns a **null exception**. And now that i understand that it's because it cant locate my image i'm assuming it's because im giving the program an incorrect path..

```
Image image = new Image(getClass().getResource("Data/Images/Logo.jpg").toExternalForm());
Label logoLabel = new Label("Logo", new ImageView(image));
```

I'm trying to get an image saved on the **JavaFX programs's Directory/Data/Images/Logo.jpg**
How do i go about reaching that location?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
getClass().getResource("/Data/Images/Logo.jpg")
```

or

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Data/Images/Logo.jpg")
```